# ksqlDB shows wrong `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` format for timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I used `kafka-connect` to stream a table from `MySQL` to a kafka topic. The table contained some columns with datetime(6) column type liked this `1611290740285818`.

When I converted this timestamp to string using ksqlDB using:

```sql
    SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(my_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS','UTC') AS DT6
      FROM my_topic
      EMIT CHANGES;
```

The displayed string was actually `+53114-10-20 14:12:20.712000`, while the actual time was supposed to be `2021-01-22 04:45:40.285818`.

Can anyone advise what was wrong with my query?

Comment: I am sure it is because milliseconds are expected but microseconds provided. Use the substring function for my_timestamp to cut its last three digits.

Comment: @AydinK.Thanks for your reply. But can you please share more details? I thought this format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS' was microseconds.

Comment: sure. 1611290740285818 is an unix timestamps in microseconds format. 
Try SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(SUBSTRING(my_timestamp,0,13), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS','UTC') AS DT6
      FROM my_topic
      EMIT CHANGES;

Comment: @AydinK. Thanks heaps for your hints. The issue was indeed caused by milliseconds and microseconds distortion. However, I have to convert my_timestamp from bigint to string, before applying the substring function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Aydin is correct in their answer. The bigint value you you shared is microseconds, and ksqlDB's [`TIMESTAMPTOSTRING`](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/scalar-functions/#timestamptostring) function expects *milliseconds*. The time format string that you specified is just telling ksqlDB how to format the timestamp, not how to interpret it. Here's an example:

```sql
-- Create a sample stream
ksql> CREATE STREAM TMP (TS BIGINT) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TMP', PARTITIONS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------

-- Populate it with example data
ksql> INSERT INTO TMP VALUES (1611290740285818);

-- Query the stream from the beginning
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';
>
Successfully changed local property 'auto.offset.reset' from 'earliest' to 'earliest'.

-- Reproduce the described behaviour
ksql> SELECT TS, TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(TS, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS','UTC') FROM TMP EMIT CHANGES;
+--------------------+------------------------------+
|TS                  |KSQL_COL_0                    |
+--------------------+------------------------------+
|1611290740285818    |+53029-10-09 09:11:25.818000  |
^CQuery terminated
```

By dividing the microseconds by 1000 they become milliseconds, and the function behaves as you would expect:

```sql
ksql> SELECT TS, 
             TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(TS/1000, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS','UTC') 
        FROM TMP 
      EMIT CHANGES;
+------------------+-------------------------+
|TS                |KSQL_COL_0               |
+------------------+-------------------------+
|1611290740285818  |2021-01-22 04:45:40.285  |
```

Comment: A perfect solution. Thanks, Robin.  BTW, I am learning kafka by watching your youtube videos. Thanks for all the amazing contents!

Comment: How to handle nulls when using TIMESTAMPTOSTRING, i.e. if TS have null values.